# How do I display an HTML property using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a working fiddle built on AngularJS v1.2.12: http://jsfiddle.net/X4Xd3/

The issue I'm running into is this:  I'm returning an array of objects from a web service. (The fiddle simplifies this by hard-coding an array.)  Each object in the array has a property that contains a string of html, and I'd like to render this to the page.  I've accomplished this by looping over the array and creating an extra property via $sce.

```js
function ctrl($scope, $sce, $log) {
    $scope.friends = [
        {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy', notes: '<p class="p">This is <strong>html</strong> content!</p>'},
        {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl', notes: '<p class="p">&laquo; This is <strong>html</strong> content!</p>'}
    ];

    for(var i = 0;i < $scope.friends.length; i++) {
        $scope.friends[i].trustedNotes = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.friends[i].notes);
    }
}
```

*If the data looks familiar, it's because I borrowed it from the AngularJS docs on [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).*

I've tested the following ways of binding to the html:

```html
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        {{ friend.notes }} <!-- shows escaped html; I expected this -->

        {{ friend.trustedNotes }} <!-- also shows escaped html -->

        <div ng-bind-html="friend.trustedNotes"></div> <!-- works, but wraps html in div -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, my question is two-fold:

1. is this "for-loop" approach the best way to display the html for each object?
2. is it possible to use `ngBindHtml` without a wrapping element?

Comment: You can probably create a raw HTML filter so that it'd look like `{{ friend.trustedNotes | raw }}`

Answer (score 0):

To address your 2nd question, if you just want the HTML set as the innerHTML of the `<li>`, you can apply `ng-bind-html` to the `<li>` itself:

```
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-bind-html="friend.trustedNotes"></li>
```